# PHP: Why does binding variables reduce SQL injections?

Tags: binding

I understand that binding reduces SQL injections, but why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding moves the responsibility for proper, platform-correct escaping to the binding API implementation. As such it's something the programmer can no longer forget or screw up, causing unforeseen and unwanted injection issues.

For a good read check http://khlo.co.uk/index.php/1302-addslashes-allows-sql-injection-attacks. It explains of the problems addslashes() had in PHP, and the consequences of depending on programmers to actively escape.

Comment: So binding basically sanitizes the input for you?

Comment: Yes and no. Sanitation usually refers to the process of validating input against unwanted data. Binding implictly moves responsibility for that to the API you're using. That means that if MySQL or whichever DBMS you use change something tomorrow in their syntax, you don't care - the API is changed to use a new escaping strategy, and your code remains safe for eternity.

Comment: Also, how do you index bound values?                          For example, suppose I have: oci_parse($handler, "SELECT * FROM table where something = :bv_name['index']")

Comment: In more advanced API's such as .NET the binding API can also do some sanitation, such as type and requirement checking. It's not required of a 'basic' binding facility though.

Comment: That depends entirely on your platform of choice and is offtopic in this question.